# Error reading the Fields of a class using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, decompiling

I have a very strange case decompiling a class.

The class has this three fields:

```
private String descError;
private Number codError;
private List<String> errorList;
```

When I decompile the class with FernFlower or JDGui I can see the three fields with no problem, but when I load the .jar containing the class into my classLoader, this class has a "Map" instead of a "List".

I obtain a :

```
java.lang.reflect.Field
```

With this properties:

Signature: `Ljava/util/Map<Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;>;`

Type: `interface java.util.Map`

class: Myclass

Anyone knows what can be the cause of this strange case?

Here my code:

```
private List<MyObjects> loadClass(String clazz, URLClassLoader completeClassLoader) {
    Class<?> loadClass = completeClassLoader.loadClass(clazz);
    Field[] classFields = loadClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field fAux : classFields) {
        //My code
    }
}
```

loadClass.getDeclaredFields returns this array of types:

```
[
private java.lang.String MyClass.fieldName1, 
private java.lang.Number MyClass.fieldName2, 
private java.util.Map MyClass.fieldName3
]
```

Instead of the real types:

```
[
private java.lang.String MyClass.fieldName1, 
private java.lang.Number MyClass.fieldName2, 
private java.util.List MyClass.fieldName3
]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to get the fields you wanted?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have added the code.

Comment: Solved the JAR has two Classes with the Same name and more or less the same package.

Comment: Awesome, just mark your question as answered, I posted my own code as well if you want it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public static void run(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("com.testing.reflection.MyClass");// this is where you would specify which class you want, use your own method to plugin the string, it needs to be the full package along with the class name
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        String modifierType = Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers()) + " ";//this will return the modifier each field has in the class
        String fieldType = field.getType().getSimpleName() + " ";// this will return the data type of each field in the class
        System.out.println(modifierType + fieldType + field.getName() + "\n");// field.getName() will return the name of each field in the class
    }
}
```

its very basic and you can implement it in your own way but it works, this is the result when I run it

```
private String descError

private Number codError

private List errorList
```

Answer (score 0):

@[christiaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5519054/christiaan)'s answer is OK.
But I modified your method a little and I gotexactly the right types:

```
private java.lang.String TestClass.descErrorprivate 
java.lang.Number TestClass.codErrorprivate 
java.util.List TestClass.errorList

private void loadClass(final String clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
   final Class<?> loadClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(clazz);
   final Field[] classFields = loadClass.getDeclaredFields();
   for (final Field fAux : classFields) {
      System.out.printf("%s", fAux);
   }
}
```